# managing double array python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code which do a quite simple thing with python :
I have a file with 10 000 lines, each lines contains between 12 and 16 numbers, and I would like to put all those data into a big array of array (table10000*16), so I wrote a little function :
(PS: line[i] is the ith line of my file, as a string)

```
def tabl(self):        
    self.table=[[0]*16]*len(self.line)
    for k,vertex in enumerate(self.line) :
        try:
            inf=[float(i) for i in vertex.split(" ")]
        except:
            pass
        for j,data in enumerate(inf):
            self.table[k][j]=data
```

The problem is that instead of putting the value of data in the cell (k,j) of my double array table, python put the value of data in all cell (n,j) for n in [0,10 000]... I don't understand where I told him to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your table like so:

```
table=[[0]*16]*len(self.line)
```

it creates an array of references. So try this:

```
self.table = [[ 0 for _ in range(16)] for _ in range(len(self.line))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here: `self.table=[[0]*16]*len(self.line)`
Python does not copy this `[0]*16` array, but copies references to it. Then, you have an array that contains many references to the same subarray. Example:

```
>>> a = [[]] * 2
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
>>>
```